# JavaScript regex - Format decimal with trailing zero and string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have different format of prices, which needs to be displayed as below:

```
1.09-----> 1.09
1.00----> 1
1.00 lb --->1lb
1.09 lb---->1.09lb
```

I need help in building the regex for JavaScript to display the above prices in specified formats.

Answer (score 1):

Parse and format the numeric portion using `parseFloat` and `Number.toString`. Add a special case to handle LBs:

```
function formatPrice(price) {
    return parseFloat(price) + (price.match(/ .+$/) ? price.match(/ (.+)$/)[1] : "");
}

console.log(formatPrice("1.00"));    // 1
console.log(formatPrice("1.09"));    // 1.09
console.log(formatPrice("1.09000")); // 1.09
console.log(formatPrice("1.00 lb")); // 1lb
console.log(formatPrice("1.09 lb")); // 1.09lb
console.log(formatPrice("1.09 kg")); // 1.09kg
```

Comment: Is it needed to use replace two times?

Comment: @user3218114: no actually. In fact, no need to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
> "1.09 lb".replace(/\.00|\s+/g, "");
'1.09lb'
> "1.00 lb".replace(/\.00|\s+/g, "");
'1lb'
> "1.00".replace(/\.00|\s+/g, "");
'1'
> "1.09".replace(/\.00|\s+/g, "");
'1.09'
```

To remove more than two zero's,

```
> "1.000".replace(/\.00+|\s+/g, "");
'1'
```

Comment: then this `"1.0".replace(/\.0+|\s+/g, "");`

Comment: what about `1.09`. will return 19.

Comment: then this `"1.0".replace(/\.0+(?=\b)|\s+/g, "");`

Comment: that's correct. Just use `\s*` otherwise `1.0lb` will be not converted properly. You know it already `\s` is used for whitespace not for only space. it will match new line character as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
\.0+\s*(\D*)$|[ ]+
```

Replacement : `$1`

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/hH6tZ3/4)

Sample code:

```
var re = /\.0+\s*(\D*)$|[ ]+/g;
var str = '1.09\n1.00\n1.00 lb\n1.09 lb';
var subst = '$1';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

output:

```
1.09
1
1lb
1.09lb
```